# Spring Batch - Passing request body object from controller to spring batch reader

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm currently building a spring boot app. This app uses Spring Batch.
So, what I'm going to achieve is this :

1. User accesses url /api/batch which is a POST method, so there'll be a request body passed to the controller.
2. The request body is passed to Spring Batch reader so the reader can read the request body.
3. Then spring batch executes the job.

I've been searching for the answer but I found nothing. I've found this : https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-reading-information-from-a-rest-api/. But the batch reader reads from a GET url not POST.
Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Comment: confused about order of point # 2 & 3 . Reader is part of batch job so how can job executes after reader has read something? Its always that first job starts then reader starts reading.

Comment: Why not just inject the values from the POST as a `JobParameter` and create a custom `ItemReader` that returns that?